# Make matplotlib figure recognize changes to rc parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am unable to "update" a figure after making changes to matplotlib's options with `plt.rc(...)`.

(I am using Python 3.6.8 in interactive mode with IPython.)

Here's (a minimal example of) what I'm trying to do:

```
In [1]: %matplotlib tk                                                                
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                               
In [3]: plt.rc('axes', labelsize=5)                                                   
In [4]: fig = plt.figure()                                                            
In [5]: plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])                                                    
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ffb128accc0>]
In [6]: fig.get_axes()[0].set_xlabel('This is the x label')                           
Out[6]: Text(0.5, 23.52222222222222, 'This is the x label')
In [7]: plt.rc('axes', labelsize=20)                                                  
In [8]: fig.canvas.draw()
```

This produces a plot with a very small x-axis label. Unfortunately, after

```
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=20)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

the label size does *not* update.

According to [this documenation](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-update-plot/) I assumed `fig.canvas.draw()` would do the trick.

Background: I have a couple of pickled figure objects which I need to adjust after loading.

Comment: Most rcParameters take effect when the respective object is created. Changing axes properties *after* the axes is created has no effect.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is unfortunate. I have quite a few pickled figures where I need to adjust the label size. Am I out of luck in the sense that I have to re-create all the figures from scratch?

Comment: No need to recreate them from scratch. But you need to change the attributes of the artists via their API. E.g. `fig.get_axes()[0].title.set_fontsize(20)` in this case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest well, that's not optimal but at least not horrible. Maybe there's a way I can "paste" the old figure data into a new one? If not, feel free to type up your answer.

Comment: You could, in the sense of `data = fig.get_axes()[0].lines[0].get_data()`, create a new figure, plot `plt.plot(*data)` in it. But that would really only be practical if there is only some lines in the old figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest no, unfortunately my real plots have more elements (patches in barplots, for example).

Comment: Yeah, that makes it pretty cumbersome. Plotly and mpld3 have scrappers that try to analyse a matplotlib figure in order to recreate it in a different format and they fail even with very simple stuff (and still are some 100s of codelines long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most rcParameters take effect when the respective object is created. Changing axes properties *after* the axes is created has no effect.

You could create a new figure and axes of course. Or, you can change the attributes of the existing artists via their API. E.g.

```
fig.get_axes()[0].title.set_fontsize(20)
```

in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to adjust all the relevant parameters through the API. This involved a lot of searching and trial and error, though. I wonder, do you happen to know whether there's any documentation listing plot API and rc-parameter which do the same side by side? (For example, sometimes the keyword-argument is named fontsize, but the rc parameter is named labelsize, very confusing.)

Comment: No, I am not aware of any such list.